# RStudio keyboard shortcuts in the console/interpreter

Tags: r, keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio

I saw a presentation by Hadley Wickham where, when the console was the active window, he was able to make the cursor jump forward/backward without using the mouse. How does that work, and is there documentation somewhere? It's not in the official list of RStudio keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [the docs](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts):

- Move cursor to beginning of line:

  - Windows & Linux: `Home`
  - Mac: `Command+Left`
- Move cursor to end of line:

  - Windows & Linux: `End`
  - Mac: `Command+Right`

Comment: Also on Windows (apparently, from playing around), Alt-Left and Alt-Right goes to the beginning or end of the line. Ctrl-Left and Ctrl-Right jumps the cursor to the nearest word beginning/ending in the specified direction.